Identify bad data in logs that is ignored by value.json.ignore-parse-errors configuration in FlinkSQL
I have flinksql enrichment job that reads from kafka topic in json format representing a table.
Producer, for some reason, producing wrong data in date columns that cause my job serializtion error and cause my flinksql job to fail.
Identified this configuration 'value.json.ignore-parse-errors' = 'true' and this makes the job keep running but ignore the records.
I would like to know the logs of such messages/records so that i can communicate to my upstream to fix the data.
